# How is perl -i *really* implemented?

Tags: perl, stdin

In the description of the Perl `-i[extension]` feature at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html, code that is materially identical to the following program is given as "an equivalent" to using `perl -pi.orig ...`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $extension = '.orig';
my $oldargv = '';
my $backup;
LINE: while (<>) {
    if ($ARGV ne $oldargv) {
        if ($extension !~ /\*/) {
            $backup = $ARGV . $extension;
        } else {
            ($backup = $extension) =~ s/\*/$ARGV/g;
        }
        rename($ARGV, $backup);
        open(ARGVOUT, ">$ARGV");
        select(ARGVOUT);
        $oldargv = $ARGV;
    }
    # Don't change anything; just copy.
}
continue {
    print;
}
select(STDOUT);
```

This works fine when `$extension eq '.orig'`; however, Perl defines `-i` with no extension as well (that is, for `$extension eq ''`). Perl's defined behavior is to edit the file in place, with no backup file created:

> If no extension is supplied, and your system supports it, the original
>   file is kept open without a name while the output is redirected to a
>   new file with the original filename. When perl exits, cleanly or not,
>   the original file is unlinked.

Perhaps my system (Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3) doesn't support it.

If I set `$extension = ''` in this program, then the code will work fine for files smaller than one block of STDIN (4096 bytes in AcivePerl 5.10, but 8192 bytes by ActivePerl 5.16), but it will **not** work for files larger than one block.

It looks to me that, on my system, if `$ARGV` and `$backup` have the same value (which they will if `$extension eq ''`, then the `open(ARGVOUT, ">$ARGV")` call on line 17 clobbers the input file after one block of it has been read.

I can work around this, of course, by writing to a temporary file and then renaming it at the end. But I'm a bit disappointed, after a couple hours of debugging, that the example in perlrun isn't as general-purpose as I had expected.

1. Is there a standard, idiomatic way to deal with the `$extension eq ''` case?
2. Is this `$extension eq ''` use-case important enough that perlrun should be edited? Of course, the "and your system supports it" clause means that the example is not incorrect, but the example would be more useful if it covered this case, too.

Comment: The reason the example program is correct is that the example program is about `-i.orig`, not about `-i` with no extension. I don't know why you expect the example program to behave like `-i` if you merely delete the `.orig` inside the program. (That's like seeing `5 * 5 == 25` and assuming that therefore `8 * 8 == 28`.) Its correctness has nothing to do with the "and your system supports it" clause, which is about whether your system supports keeping an open handle to an unlinked file.

Comment: (By the way, it's not `-i ''`, but just bare `-i` with no argument. And string comparison uses `eq`, not `==`.)

Comment: Though you could write it `-i''`.

Comment: @ruakh, I'm sensitive to your point about `5 * 5`, but this is an example that is supposed to show how Perl works, and I don't think that it is irrational to have felt a little bit misled by the example. To follow your analogy, it's as if you told me that some function `f(a, b)` for `(a, b) = (5, 5)` is "equivalent to" the code `a * b`, but not mentioning that the code is different when `a` and `b` have other permissible values.

Comment: Are you actually trying to use this code in a script, or are you simply curious how `-i` works? If the former, you can include flags on the shebang line, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/perl -pi`

Comment: No. It's supposed to show how `perl -p -i.orig -e 's/foo/bar/;'` works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Perl 5.28 [changed `-i`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5280delta.pod#In-place-editing-with-perl-i-is-now-safer). This answer pertains to earlier versions of Perl.*

---

When an extension is provided:

```
open(my $fh_in,  '<', $qfn);
rename($qfn, "$qfn$ext");
open(my $fh_out, '>', $qfn);
```

This can be seen using `strace`.

```
$ strace perl -i~ -pe1 a
...
open("a", O_RDONLY)                     = 3
rename("a", "a~")                       = 0
open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
...
```

---

When no extension is provided:

```
open(my $fh_in,  '<', $qfn);
unlink($qfn);
open(my $fh_out, '>', $qfn);
```

This can be seen using `strace`.

```
$ strace perl -i -pe1 a
...
open("a", O_RDONLY)                     = 3
unlink("a")                             = 0
open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
...
```

---

Unix systems such as Macs support anonymous files. Windows does not, so `-i` requires an extension there.

```
>perl -i.bak -pe1 a

>perl -i -pe1 a
Can't do inplace edit without backup.
```

---

If we integrate this knowledge in the code you posted, we get the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $extension = '.orig';
my $oldargv = '';
my $backup;
LINE: while (<>) {
    if ($ARGV ne $oldargv) {
        if (length($extension)) {
            if ($extension !~ /\*/) {
                $backup = $ARGV . $extension;
            } else {
                ($backup = $extension) =~ s/\*/$ARGV/g;
            }
            rename($ARGV, $backup);
        } else {
            die("Can't do inplace edit without backup.\n") if $^O eq 'MSWin32';
            unlink($ARGV);
        }
        open(ARGVOUT, ">$ARGV");
        select(ARGVOUT);
        $oldargv = $ARGV;
    }
    # Don't change anything; just copy.
}
continue {
    print;
}
select(STDOUT);
```

Comment: and cygwin just quietly defaults bare -i to mean -i.bak (presumably for better support of existing shell scripts)

Comment: @ysth, Then odd thing is that the unlink trick works in cygwin. (No idea how.) Maybe it didn't used to work? Or maybe there's some limitations?

Comment: it's been a long time, so I probably misremember, but it was something like setting a delete on close flag in via the win32 api or actually deleting it in an exit handler or both?  and maybe with limitations (another process having it open too?)

Comment: @ysth, That wouldn't work. The file needs to be gone before it's closed. I'm guessing it renames it to somewhere else on the disk.

Comment: I don't think it used to, see e.g. http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/79103.  But the cygwin source file cited there doesn't exist anymore, so maybe windows actually supports it now?

Comment: @ysth, If it used that, that explains the hack in Perl.